# Sharing Video to Facebook - Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm writing an app to try and post a video to Facebook.  Ideally I'd like to pull the video from Parse, and convert it to a NSURL.  Right now I am trying to use an ImagePicker to pick the photo used to share.

Right now I have the ImagePicker showing up, but I'm getting two errors. 1)Only Photos are showing up in the roll and 2) I'm getting a 'found nil while unwrapping Optional value' in my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function.  For issue 1, I have changed the UIImagePickerControllerSourceType to .PhotoLibrary but it still omitted the videos.

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     let profileButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .Done, target: self, action: "videoBtnClicked")
     self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(profileButton, animated: true)

  func videoBtnClicked(){
      if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
          print("Video capture")
          imagePicker.delegate = self
          imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
          imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
          self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
      let video : FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()
          //error occurs line below here       
          video.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
      let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
      content.video = video
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For photo only question

> ```
> func videoBtnClicked(){
>   if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
>       print("Video capture")
>       imagePicker.delegate = self
>       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
>       **imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]**
>       imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
>       self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
>     }
> }
> ```

2. For second question,you should check url first

> ```
> func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {      
>   let video : FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()
>       //error occurs line below here       
>   if let url = video.videoURL{
>       video.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
>       let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
>       content.video = video
>   }
> }
> ```